# I need help creating a SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to come up with a report that looks something like this:

[image]

There are 3 tables Agents, Sales and Payments. Sales and Payments are linked via the Agents table. The report is to show the total daily sales per Agent per day. It also needs to show for each day any payments the agent has made and this is to be deducted from the total sales balance such that any any point in time we can tell if the Agent owes the business or vice versa.

The way I plan to tackle this is:

- Get all sales per agent per day (one query)
- Get all payments per agent per day (one query)
- For each Sales, agent and each day check (agents payments per agent per day) (loop)
- If match is found get value and use for calculation with cumulative total
- Otherwise just display appropriate sale data only with cumulative total.

I'm not sure if there is query that can make my life a bit easier. Thanks.

[Edit]

**Agents Table:**
id,
name,
opening_balance

**Sales Table:**
id,
agent_id,
amount,
customer_id,
sale_date

**Payments Table:**
id,
agent_id,
amount,
bank_id,
payment_date,
status

[2nd Edit]

Thanks Olaf Dietsche. The second query without the sub-select took a long time to run. About 88 secs. I also tried the first on with the sub-select and it completed in a flash however the sum(s.amount) and sum(p.amount) hold values twice what they should be.

[image]

[3rd Edit]

An agent can make multiple sales and 
An agent can make multiple payments

There is no direct connection between sales and payments

Comment: these are all connected by the 'agent', I could help you write a single query to join these if you provide table details (column names).

Comment: Please post the tables' structures. What you need is a `JOIN` and a `GROUP BY` with an aggregate functions, then it will be the problem of cumulative totals.

Comment: Can you post more details about the agent table?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first cut

```
select a.name, s.sale_date, sum(s.amount), sum(p.amount),
       (select sum(amount)
        from sales
        where agent_id = a.id and sale_date <= s.sale_date) as cum_sales,
       (select sum(amount)
        from payments
        where agent_id = a.id and payment_date <= s.sale_date) as cum_payments
from agents a
join sales s on s.agent_id = a.id
join payments p on p.agent_id = a.id
group by s.agent_id, s.sale_date
order by s.agent_id, s.sale_date
```

The cumulative balance would be `opening_balance - cum_sales + cum_payments`.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87769/15/0)

Here is a select without subselects. This *might* be faster

```
select a.name, s.sale_date, sum(s.amount), sum(p.amount),
       sum(cs.amount) as cum_sales,
       sum(cp.amount) as cum_payments
from agents a
join sales s on s.agent_id = a.id
join payments p on p.agent_id = a.id
join sales cs on cs.agent_id = a.id and cs.sale_date <= s.sale_date
join payments cp on cp.agent_id = a.id and cp.payment_date <= s.sale_date
group by s.agent_id, s.sale_date
order by s.agent_id, s.sale_date
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87769/17/0)

Both are untested, since I don't have data to do so.